# Rails can't find javascript file from gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am having trouble including the **highcharts** JS in my rails app when using the **highcharts-rails gem**.

I have added the gem to my gemfile

`gem "highcharts"`

And then ran `bundle install`

In my **application.js** file I have used (as described on the [repo](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails))

`//= require highcharts`

But I keep getting the error

`Sprockets::FileNotFound` for `highcharts`

Comment: try precompiling the assets.It may work

Comment: It precompiled with no errors but still same error on page load.

Comment: could you paste the application.js file content

Comment: did you restart rails server after `bundle install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [`highcharts-rails` gem](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails) to allow using highcharts in a [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) application. So:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require highcharts
```

Then:

```
$ bundle install
```

Alternatively you can use [`highcharts-js-rails` gem](https://github.com/agrobbin/highcharts-js-rails), or [`lazy_high_charts` gem](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts). The latter is most newly updated.

Comment: this is the right answer, the OP is including the wrong gem.

Comment: Is there any way to physically find a javascript file that was added/installed from a gem? Where are these files stored? In my case I need to check if something is there and try to override it in order to come to a solution and make a pull request.

Comment: @Tashows usually in bundled tree, either with grep/find or with aim of railties

Answer (score -1):

Create a highcharts.js blank file and see if the charts and all are working or not .. i had same issue with highlighter.js , i simply created a blank file highlighter.js and it worked .